# JQuery stopPropagation on .live() when handlers already exist

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I'm aware that live calls bubble up through the doccument and that is why I'm having issues.

Unfortunately I'm using third party libraries that bind event handlers to elements and would like to create a case in which a click event isn't bubbled up to those elements.

using .click() in combination with eventStopPropagation() works just fine, however due to the dynamic nature of the content I need to use either live,on,delegate,etc...
Here's a fidddle of my issue. I need to prevent "middle" click from firing when clicking the "inner" div. I can **not** change the "middle" handler (it is best if you consider I don't even have access to it).

Thanks in advance for your help!! And sorry for the repeat, I thought it would be tidier this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/99zQM/9/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    outer non dynamic element
    <div id="middle">
        middle dynamic
        <div id="inner">
            inner dynamic
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#middle").bind('click',function(e){
    //is rebound when content is loaded
   alert("middle clicked"); 
});
$('#inner').live('click',function(e){
    alert("inner clicked"); 
});
```

Comment: "... that bind elements ..."?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Hi, I felt like it was unfair to those who had already answered correctly. This is a different problem altogether. I am however oblivious to stackoverflow's "guide of conduct" so I may be wrong in doing things this way.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot That bind event handlers to elements, my bad I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$(document).bind('click',function(e) {
    if (e.target)
        target = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement)
        target = e.srcElement;
    else
        target = e.currentTarget;

    if (target.id == 'middle') 
    {
    alert("middle clicked"); 
    }

       else if (target.id == 'inner')
       {
       alert("inner clicked"); 
       }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99zQM/12/

Comment: not the cleanest but desperate times call for drastic measures. I'm currently using this so I'm definitely upvoting it. In my specific case I've applied this concept to the "middle" click event (even though I said I didn't want to touch it in my question). If nothing better crops up I'll mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You would use `.on` for binding click event. For each binding to #outer, #middle and #inner.
Use stopPropagation to prevent bubble up event.

```
$("#outer").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("outer clicked"); 
});

$("#outer").on('click', '#middle', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("middle clicked"); 
});

$("#outer #middle").on('click', '#inner', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("inner clicked"); 
});
```

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/99zQM/11/

Comment: unfortunately my real life case has a few more levels, some of which have events that do need to bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to capture the click handler and dynamically wrap it in another handler which tests for event bubbling like this :

```
// Your code does not change

    $("#middle").bind('click',function(e){
        //is rebound when content is loaded
       alert("middle clicked"); 
    });

    $('#inner').live('click',function(e){
        alert("inner clicked"); 
    });

// capture the click handler on #middle and wrap it inside a test for bubbling
var handler = $._data($("#middle")[0], "events")["click"][0].handler;
$('#middle').unbind('click');

$("#middle").bind('click',(function(handlerVar){return function(e){
    if(e.target===this) // test for bubbling
    {
        handlerVar(e);
    }
}})(handler));
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/99zQM/13/

Hope this will help

Comment: I like this a lot but if I dynamically remove and reload #middle this won't work anymore? Or am I missing something? I'd love to find a way to implement this on dynamic content though

Comment: @D.Mill You will have to execute this code after each click binding on #middle. But you could wrap it in a function which you could call just after calling the bind click, which, I assume, will still be there.